# js links not working on filtered list items

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i wanted to make filtered list with input field and list options hidden so i found a code which has everything i need except the problem that when i select an option from list it doesnt redirect me to the linked page. can someone please help correct the below code.

```js
var UL = document.getElementById("myUL");
// hilde the list by default
UL.style.display = "none";

var searchBox = document.getElementById("myInput");

// show the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("focus",  function(){
    // UL.style.display = "block";
});

// hide the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    UL.style.display = "none";
});


function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // if the input is empty hide the list
    if(filter.trim().length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    } else {
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }

    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
     if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { 
        li[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    } 

    // This is when you want to find words that start the search string
    /*if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }*/
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="www.google.com/">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: isn't `searchBox.addEventListener("blur"...display="none";});` happening before click event? commenting this line out seems to make the links work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// hide the list when the input receive focus
/*searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    UL.style.display = "none";
});*/
```

This will set `display:none` when clicking the `<ul>`. It is setting `display:none` before the URL redirection.

Additionally when you linking external link you need to start it with `http://` otherwise browser identify it as a internal link.

Comment: it worked thank you so much for your help you saved me bid time.